# Error using INSERT and WITH statements together

Tags: sql, postgresql, common-table-expression, postgresql-9.2, postgresql-9.0

PostgreSQL: v9.2 on a Windows machine.

UPDATE: the version of postgres on the server is 9.0, the version on my machine is 9.2.1.

I am trying to use the following query to update a table I have created.

```
WITH
    nei_nox AS (SELECT fips, sum(total_emissions) AS x FROM nei_data WHERE 
        pollutant_name ILIKE '%nitrogen%' GROUP BY fips),
    nei_sox AS (SELECT fips, sum(total_emissions) AS x FROM nei_data WHERE 
        pollutant_name ILIKE '%sulfur%' GROUP BY fips),
    nei_co AS (SELECT fips, sum(total_emissions) AS x FROM nei_data WHERE 
        pollutant_name ILIKE '%monoxide%' GROUP BY fips),
    nei_voc AS (SELECT fips, sum(total_emissions) AS x FROM nei_data WHERE 
        pollutant_name ILIKE '%PM10%' GROUP BY fips),
    nei_nh3 AS (SELECT fips, sum(total_emissions) AS x FROM nei_data WHERE 
        pollutant_name ILIKE '%PM2.5%' GROUP BY fips),
    nei_pm10 AS (SELECT fips, sum(total_emissions) AS x FROM nei_data WHERE 
        pollutant_name ILIKE '%volatile%' GROUP BY fips),
    nei_pm25 AS (SELECT fips, sum(total_emissions) AS x FROM nei_data WHERE 
        pollutant_name ILIKE '%ammonia%' GROUP BY fips)

-- INSERT INTO nei_data_by_county
(
    SELECT dat.fips, nei_nox.x as "nox",
         nei_sox.x as "sox",
         nei_co.x as "co",
         nei_voc.x as "voc",
         nei_nh3.x as "nh3",
         nei_pm10.x as "pm10",
         nei_pm25.x as "pm25"
    FROM bts2dat_55.cg_data dat
    LEFT OUTER JOIN nei_nox ON dat.fips = nei_nox.fips
    LEFT OUTER JOIN nei_sox ON dat.fips = nei_sox.fips
    LEFT OUTER JOIN nei_co ON dat.fips = nei_co.fips
    LEFT OUTER JOIN nei_voc ON dat.fips = nei_voc.fips
    LEFT OUTER JOIN nei_nh3 ON dat.fips = nei_nh3.fips
    LEFT OUTER JOIN nei_pm10 ON dat.fips = nei_pm10.fips
    LEFT OUTER JOIN nei_pm25 ON dat.fips = nei_pm25.fips
);
```

When the I run the query in pgAdmin, the data is returned as one would expect. However, when I un-comment the `--INSERT INTO nei_data_by_county` I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "INSERT"
LINE 33: INSERT INTO nei_data_by_county
         ^
```

I know from [the documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/queries-with.html) that you are allowed to use the `WITH` statement and the `INSERT` statement together, but I cannot get this query to function properly.

Has someone else run into this problem?

Comment: The parentheses around the SELECT statement are unnecessary, but it should still just work with PostgreSQL 9.2.

Comment: The query shown seems fine, but the WITH being at line 1, the INSERT  is at line 17, yet the error tells it's at line 33. Isn't that weird?

Comment: It appears that the server I am working on is actually postgres v9.0. @ErwinBrandstetter, how could I confirm that the "insert" statement is not compatible with the "with" statement in v9.0?

Comment: @DanielVérité, the line numbers are off because there is a table definition above the query shown above. I have verified the table is properly created already.

Comment: OK. 9.0 doesn't support WITH before INSERT. [Doc excerpt](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/queries-with.html): _WITH provides a way to write subqueries for use in a larger SELECT query_. In 9.1 this has become: _WITH provides a way to write auxiliary statements for use in a larger query_

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: I tested and verified it works with parentheses in 9.1 before I posted.

Comment: @DanielVérité, thank you! Your suggestion of putting the 'INSERT' statement prior to the 'WITH' statement solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

[**Data-modifying CTEs**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING) were only introduced with PostgreSQL 9.1.
Your incorrect information (version 9.2) had everybody fooled, including yourself.

The syntax is just not possible with 9.0.

But the solution is simple: use subqueries instead:

```
INSERT INTO nei_data_by_county (<<provide column list!!>>)
SELECT dat.fips
      ,nei_nox.x   -- as "nox" -- column alias is only for you documentation
       -- more columns
FROM   bts2dat_55.cg_data dat
LEFT   OUTER JOIN (
   SELECT fips, sum(total_emissions) AS x
   FROM   nei_data
   WHERE  pollutant_name ILIKE '%nitrogen%'
   GROUP  BY fips
   ) nei_nox USING (fips)
LEFT OUTER JOIN ... -- more subqueries
```